# Finding missing values in aggregated list Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table similar to this

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | AA |
| A | AC |
| B | AB |
| B | AD |

This table is grouped by ID and I get a list of values

```
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value)
  FROM table 
 GROUP BY ID
```

All possible values are AA, AB, AC, AD. I would like to show the missing values.
So the results should be

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | AB, AD |
| B | AA, AC |

Is there any elegant way to solve this? I am working on oracle 19

Answer (score 5):

You can find all the `DISTINCT` values and then use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to find the missing ones:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       LISTAGG(v.value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.value) AS missing
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT VALUE FROM table_name) v
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY (t.id)
       ON (v.value = t.value)
WHERE  t.value IS NULL
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, VALUE) AS
SELECT 'A', 'AA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'AC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'AB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'AD' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | MISSING |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | AB, AD |
> | B | AA, AC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0ba2dd7d76577b18c8248becabab7aad)*

Comment: MTO Hello Can you pls explain your solution using that partition in join .without that the query will not work. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: @Florin A `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` is used to [fill gaps in data](https://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/270646.htm). It will take all the values from the driving table (in this case, the left one) and then join it to all values specified in the `PARTITION` clause from the right table and then `OUTER JOIN` the remaining columns on the right if they exist for the partition.

Comment: @ MTO Thank you so much for the answer and for taking time answer my question